# Best Practice for reserved words? renaming vars in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, reserved-words

Often I've found my model/var names highlighted in textmate as a reserved word
(i.e service, attr, etc.)

I'm afraid this might cause troubles and I usually change the name to something else 
(service -> srvice, attr -> atr)

I googled a bit on the subject but the search terms are a bit tricky so I didn't find much

Is there a best practice on how to rename a variable that is a reserved word? such as prefixing an underscore or whatever (_service, _attr)

Answer (score 3):

get more creative or descriptive with the name...  for example, I was converting a database to rails that had a column named `type` which is reserved for rails magic, so I renamed it to `facility_type`.  It's longer, but the name further documents what it contains.  Using an underscore at the front or omitting letters makes it *less* readable.